# How to use pumping lemma on languages that do not follow a strict structure?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

Let me preface this by saying, I do NOT want an example of a proof, I would merely like pointers as to how I could approach this problem.

For example, I have a language:
$$L = \{w \mid w \in \{0, 1\}^*,\ \#_0\ge\#_1\}$$

As you can see, 0's and 1's can occur in any order,
I have found it easy to prove this is not regular using the pumping lemma, for example the string:
$0^p1^p$ can be pumped easily.

Proving that this is not context-free, as I believe it is not context-free, has me stumped.

**EDIT**

Thanks to nir shahar, Using their example I was able to work out the issue I was having. I was able to split my PDA into two sections, one where the number of 0's was greater than the number of ones, and one where the number of 1's was greater than the number of 0's. It sort of makes a mirrored image that accounts for all possibilities. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: This is in fact, a context free language

Comment: I hate to press the issue further, but I don't quite understand how it could be possible to account for all permutations with a context free grammar when there is no given structure to the language? I find myself awfully confused as how I would be able to count any possible string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language is context free.

Here is a hint: as you have proved, it isn't regular. Therefore, when you try to construct a PDA for this language you will have to use the stack. Try to think how to count numbers using the stack, maybe start with a simpler language like $\{0^n1^m\mid n\ge m\}$. This is the main "crux" of your problem :)

Comment: I understand how to count members of a structured language with the stack such as the above example, but when the simple structure of 0^n1^m turns into a string such as "00011101100011", counting becomes a harder task for me.

Comment: The solution for the language in your question is very similar to that of the language I wrote you about. You need to make a fe small modifications, but the idea of how to count should work without the need for the "structure" in the language itself.